# Button click event not getting triggered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, android-dialog, android-tablelayout

I have a set of buttons defined within a table layout.

*custom_layout.xml* :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/firstBtn"
            android:text="F"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
        </Button>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/secondBtn"
            android:text="S"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
        </Button>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/thirdBtn"
            android:text="T"
            android:layout_weight="0.3">
        </Button>

    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This XML is set as a layout within a custom alert dialog.

**Code:**

```
public class CustomDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {


private Button firstBtn = null;
private Button secondBtn = null;
private Button thirdBtn = null;


public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setPersistent(false);
    this.context = context;
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_layout);



}

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {

    firstBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.firstBtn);
    secondBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.secondBtn);
    thirdBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.thirdBtn);

    firstBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("Check","First button is clicked"));

        }
    });

    secondBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("Check","Second button is clicked"));

        }
    });

    thirdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("Check","Third button is clicked"));

        }
    });


    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);
    persistBoolean(positiveResult);

    Log.d("Blockout","Dialog close detected");
    if(positiveResult)
    {

        Log.d("Blockout","Save button had been clicked");

    }

   }

}
```

When the dialog is opened and I click on the buttons, I am not able to see the corresponding log messages. I am also not getting any null pointer exceptions, so I think the the views are being set and accessed properly. Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: how did you open the dialog ? share your code

Comment: I am setting this dialog within a preference screen xml (not through code).. and the dialog is opening and some other elements in the custom dialog are accessible (i have not included that here since it is not relevant to the question)

Comment: make a toast replacing log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a custom Dialog, I'd suggest the `DialogFragment` class. There's a documentation guide on those  - [**Dialogs**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

I think you want this method - `onCreateDialogView`.

For example,

```
public class CustomDialogPreference extends DialogPreference 
    implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Context context;

    public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(false);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected View onCreateDialogView() {
        super.onCreateDialogView();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);

        rootView.findViewById(R.id.firstBtn).setOnClickListener(this);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.secondBtn).setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.firstBtn:
                Log.d("Check","First button is clicked"));
                break;
            case R.id.secondBtn:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, one minor correction : inflater.inflate() doesn't take a single int parameter. Edited the post with the correction.